# Как отправить несколько файлов с помощью mail php?

Tags: php

Мне нужно было написать код для автоматической отправки нескольких выбранных файлов на указанную почту. Выбор файлов оформил через чекбоксы. При проверке выдает ошибку 500. Подскажите, в чем заключается проблема?

```
<?php
    $a=$_POST['a'];
    $b=$_POST['b'];
    $c=$_POST['c'];
    $d=$_POST['d'];
    $e=$_POST['e'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $e=[];
    if($a!=0){
        $e[]=$a;
    }
    if($b!=0){
        $e[]=$b;
    }
    if($c!=0){
        $e[]=$c;
    }
    if($d!=0){
        $e[]=$d;
    }
    if($e!=0){
        $e[]=$e;
    }
    $files = array("fb2.rar","pdf.rar","epub.rar","txt.rar","mobi.rar");
    $body = "";
    

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = $email;
    $from = "no-reply@someurl.ru";
    $subject = "test";
    $message = html_entity_decode($body);
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"   {$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($e); $x++) {
        $z=$e[$x]-1;
        $file = fopen($files[$z], "rb");
        $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$z]));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$z]\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$z]\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    // send

    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($ok) {
        echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Читайте в логах сервера, что именно вызывает ошибку 500

Comment: или используйте **[Отладку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**